# Awesome Dialog not closing in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the [Awesome Dialog](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_dialog) in my flutter application but when I click on OK it just navigates to another screen and doesn't close.
here is my code.

```
    Future requestSupport(String userid, String supportType, String duration) async {
        final response =
  await http.post('http://url/api/Support',
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", 
             'Accept': 'application/json',},
  body: json.encode({'userid' : userid ,  'supportType' : supportType, 'duration' : duration}));

 if (response.statusCode == 200) {

 showAlertDialogOnOkCallback();  

    }



 }
 void showAlertDialogOnOkCallback() {
        AwesomeDialog(
              context: context,
              animType: AnimType.LEFTSLIDE,
              dialogType: DialogType.SUCCES,
              tittle: 'Success',
              desc:
                  'You have been entered into the queue, press OK to go back.',
              btnOkOnPress:  () {  },
              btnOkIcon: Icons.check_circle,
              onDissmissCallback: () {
                debugPrint('Dialog Dissmiss from callback');
              }).show();
 }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [doc](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_dialog) for this library says,

> Function that handle click of positive Button, closing the dialog is handled internally.

---

**UPDATE**: I have tried it myself and it works fine approach I used,
I took a button to open dialog,

```
     RaisedButton(
          child: Text("ok",),
          onPressed: () {
              open();
          },
        ),
```

Since dialog closing is handled by default by the library I used `Navigator.pop(context);` this to go back to the previous screen using `btnOkOnPress`

```
  void open() {
    AwesomeDialog(
        context: context,
        dialogType: DialogType.INFO,
        animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
        tittle: 'Dialog Title',
        desc:
            'Dialog description here',
        btnCancelOnPress: () {},
        btnOkOnPress: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }).show();
  }
```

Note: I navigate to screen which is having dialog by `Navigator.pushNamed`. So if `Navigator.pop(context);` is called it comes back to this screen only.

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, RouteName.ReportScreen);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yeah that didnt close it either, just took me to a blank screen with the dialog on it.

Comment: Although it seems your problem is already resolved, but I just wanted to show that my solution is working also. maybe in your case navigation between pages was wrong. See my updated answer:)

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to replicate your issue. I used a simple `RaisedButton` upon tapping on it opens `AwesomeDialog`. Then tapping on `OK` button of the dialog closes it properly. I also tested by adding a navigation upon ok button tap that closes the dialog and navigates to next screen. Code I used:

```
body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _openDialog();
          },
          child: Text('Tap')
        )
      )

void _openDialog() {
    AwesomeDialog(
        context: context,
        animType: AnimType.LEFTSLIDE,
        dialogType: DialogType.SUCCES,
        tittle: 'Success',
        desc:
        'You have been entered into the queue, press OK to go back.',
        btnOkOnPress:  () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageB()));
        },
        btnOkIcon: Icons.check_circle,
        onDissmissCallback: () {
          debugPrint('Dialog Dissmiss from callback');
        }).show();
  }
```

Console output:

```
I/flutter (13279): Dialog Dissmiss from callback
I/flutter (13279): Dialog Dissmiss from callback
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to use the **Awesome Dialogue** and then use the property "useRootNavigator" and set it to true.

```
AwesomeDialog(
        useRootNavigator: true,
        context: context,
        animType: AnimType.LEFTSLIDE,
        headerAnimationLoop: false,
        dialogType: DialogType.SUCCES,
        title: 'Go',
        desc: 'Continue Adding ',
        btnOkOnPress: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
        },
        btnOkIcon: Icons.receipt,
        onDissmissCallback: () {
          debugPrint('Dialog Dissmiss from callback');
        },
        btnOkText: "Add More members",
        btnCancelOnPress: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
        },
        btnCancelIcon: Icons.home,
        btnCancelText: "Go to Home Page")
      ..show();
```